# How to setup screen sharing for business meetings?

Tags: remote-control, vnc, screen-sharing

I'm wondering if it would be possible to use android-based tablets (or ipads) in business meetings.

The idea would be to have each person in the meeting, with its individual tablet, see what a "meeting-leader" is seeing on his own tablet, navigating through the web or using apps.

I see some solutions that seem to be mostly directed into remote-control, but what I want is just to screencast in realtime to multiple receivers, privately. The ability to let some other person take control would also be nice, but not mandatory.

How could I set this up?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I was wondering if you found a solution to your question. I am facing the same issue; I need to share my android tablet screen with a different android tablet. It would be helpful if I can find any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may use join.me for this. The organizer installs the client on his/ her machine and rest everyone may join in through their web browser.

Comment: Didn't know about it. Seems an interesting utility, but it seems to enforce that the "meeting-leader" has a windows machine, and ideally in my setup, everyone would use tablets, including the "meeting-leader".

I'm hoping for something better, but maybe this is the best there is, who knows.

Comment: An Android device can't initiate a meeting using joinme, it can only join a meeting initiated by a windows pc or linux computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice little app by Smart Dog Studio called [Remote Control Add On](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.xdevelop.rc&hl=en) that will let your device act as a VNC server.  You can then connect as many clients as you like using the VNC client of your choice (I usually use [Android VNC Viewer](https://market.android.com/details?id=android.androidVNC&hl=en)).

Frame rate is a little low, but definitely adequate for a presentation that doesn't involve video.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for this: [Screen Stream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial).
I use it and it works.