# How can I share my screen from Android device to another Android device?

Tags: screen-sharing

I hand my clients an Xoom (Android tablet) and I am holding a Xoom.

How do I simply have them watch what I'm doing on my screen? No video, audio, or anything else fancy needed. All I need is a simple screen share. Will be showing documents, webpages, and such.

Join.me and GoToMeeting only allow view mode, not share mode on Android. There has to be a program to allow this.

Comment: Related, but *not duplicate:* [Is there a way to share my mobile screen with another Android phone like Netmeeting or Live Meeting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/16575), [How to setup screen sharing for business meetings?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/16575)

Answer (score 3):

Try this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.springdesign.screenshare.browser.server). It allows you to share the screens between two tablets or two mobile devices of varying dimensions wirelessly and does not require any thing extra as per your requirements.

Comment: This is amazing should be accepted as an answer and get a reward :) thanks so much! @user285oo6 do you know of any website that can do this without downloading an app? like https://kosmi.io on PC?

Comment: Unfortunately the link is down ;(

Answer (score -1):

There is a TeamViewer app that acts as a server "TeamViewer Quick support" unfortunately it is for samsung devices only

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like some kind of VNC type of solution would be the best, maybe [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/mobile.aspx)? You might need an enterprise license if you're doing this for commercial purposes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the TeamViewer app is only a client, not a server. You can view a computer running TV, but you can't share your screen.

Comment: Oh right, my fault. Seems like something TeamViewer should fix eventually though, as anyone with a rooted Android device surely has the rights to start a server, and there's already a TeamViewer server solution for desktop Linux.